# Dont know how to fix popen ,"Invalid file object" error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to get a file name and pass it to a command using popen. Then I want to print the output. This is my code:

```
filePath = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("All files", "*.*")])

fileNameStringForm = (basename(filePath ))
fileNameByteForm = fileNameStringForm.encode(encoding='utf-8')

process = subprocess.Popen(['gagner','-arg1'], shell = True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process .communicate(fileNameByteForm )

stdout, stderr = process .communicate()  <<------ERROR POINTS TO THIS LINE

stringOutput = stdout.decode('urf-8')
print(stringOutput)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid file object: <_io.BufferedReader name=9>
```

I have looked at other similar questions but nothing seems to have solved my problem. Can some show me where I am going wrong in the code?

**Edit:**
If I were to run the command in a command line it would be:

```
gagner -arg1 < file1
```

Comment: Why are you calling `communicate()` twice?

Comment: @jsfan First one is to sent the file name to stdin, And the second is to recieve stdout and stderr into a variable so that they can be printed.

Comment: Have you tried doing it in one line, i.e. `process.communicate(fileNameByteForm)`?

Comment: @jsfan Sorry, I am not sure what you mean my this. If I were to just include `process.communicate(fileNameByteForm)`, then how would I recieve the stdout to print.

Comment: I also called communicate() twice and that was what caused the problem for me. But only on Linux. It worked on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is not what you are describing in the supposed command line argument. You are actually executing this:

```
echo "file1" | gagner -arg1
```

You will need to make sure that you pass in the file contents yourself. Popen will not open and read the file for you.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), what `communicate()` does is

> interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.

So, once you have run

```
process.communicate(fileNameByteForm)
```

your sub process has finished and the pipes have been closed. The second call will then fail as a result.

What you want to do instead is

```
stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input_data)
```

which will pipe your input data into the sub process and read stdout and stderr.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. Do you know how I would be able to do it for this `gagner -arg1 < file1`?